# Fork, execlp and kill. Zombie process

Tags: linux, fork, kill, zombie-process

I have a c program that executes another process (bash script) with fork and execlp. When I want to kill this process it moves to a zombiee state. Why is this??

Create a process:

```
    switch (PID_BackUp= fork())
    {
      case -1:
          perror("fork");
          printf("An error has occurred launching backup.sh script!\n");
          break;

      case 0:
          execlp("/usr/local/bin/backup.sh", "/usr/local/bin/backup.sh", NULL, NULL, NULL);
          break;

      default:
          printf("backup.sh script launched correctly! PID: %d\n", PID_BackUp);
          break;
    }
```

Kill a process:

```
    if(kill(PID_BackUp,SIGKILL)==-1)
        fprintf(stderr, "No se ha podido matar el programa: %d\n", PID_BackUp);
    else
        printf("\nProceso con identificador %d, se ha abortado\n", PID_BackUp);
```

So at this point the process moves to a zombie state. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) or some other waiting system call ([wait4(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait4.2.html)...) to avoid having [zombie processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process). BTW you may also handle the `SIGCHLD` signal to be notified when a child process has terminated (or changed state).

Generally, you'll better first [kill(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) a process with `SIGTERM` (and only later, with `SIGKILL`) since that process -your `backup.sh` script- could handle correctly (using `trap` builtin in the shell script) the signal (but `SIGKILL` cannot be caught, and the backup could e.g. leave clutter or useless files on the disk). See also [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) & [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html)

Read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) (we can't explain what is taught by that freely available book in several chapters in only a few paragraphs).

BTW, better use [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) or `strerror(errno)` in messages when a system call fails.

Comment: So, should the process that use fork be waiting (waitpid) for the child process?? I am using fork in my general program (embedded platform) so I can´t stay waiting the child process (I would have to create an specific thread)

Comment: Yes, at some point you should `wait` or `waitpid`. However, read more about `SIGCHLD`